# destroyItem being called when position ==2 why? android pagerAdapter

Tags: android

I have a very simple PagerAdapter that for some reason, removes the views at position 0 and 
1 when it is scrolled to position 2.

Specifically, when I first run the app, there are 3 views. I scroll to position 2 and position 1's view will disappear. View 0 is still there. If I scroll to view 0 and back to view 2 and again back to view 0, View 0 suddenly disappears. I do the same again, and I can actually see view 0 being instantiated and immediately destroyed.

what is going on here?

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this);
        final ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.mypanelpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}


public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context ctx;
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
ViewGroup collection;

public MyPagerAdapter (Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx ;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position ){
    this.collection = (ViewPager)container;
    NewMonth monthObject = new NewMonth(ctx, month+position-1,2012);
    View monthLayout = monthObject.newParentLayout;
    collection.addView(monthLayout);
    return monthLayout;
    return addViewAt(position);
    }


@Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    collection.removeViewAt(position);
}


 @Override
     public Parcelable saveState() {
     return null;
     }


@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object arg1) {
    return view==arg1;
}
}
```

Comment: Probably the issue is in collection.addView(monthLayout); line. Have You tried to remove it? It probably would be better to have own collection instead of using ViewPager itself for that purpose.

Comment: @sandrstar nope that's not the issue, Removing the collection.addView(monthLayout) results in nothing being shown.

Comment: @sandrstar I believe the view was removed due to collection.removeViewAt(position) because there wouldn't be anything else that would remove a view

Comment: right, seems my suggestion was wrong, you did it the right way - looks like views should be added and removed from the adapter. Checkout populate() function from ViewPager source - it has clear checks then to remove currentIndex+1 and currentIndex-1 items (it actually seems to depend on views sizes).

Comment: @sandrstar do you have a link? I can't seem to locate it on the developer page of ViewPager

Comment: yep, it's actually located under Your android sdk: <android sdk folder>\extras\android\support\v4\src\java\android\support\v4\view\ViewPager.java. Moreover, You can just attach mentioned above code and debug ViewPager behaviour without problems.

Comment: You have two return statements in your `instantiateItem()` method. The second one will never be reached; I'm surprised it even compiled that way without an "unreachable code" warning.

Answer (score 6):

You have to maintain all tabs in memory specifying the OffscreenPageLimit to N-1, in your case put this inside the onCreate method:

```
myPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout `populate()` function from `ViewPager` source - it has clear checks then to remove currentIndex+1 and currentIndex-1 items. Removing is done based on view sizes and it seems to be entirely internal ViewPager logic. ViewPager source is located

```
<android sdk folder>\extras\android\support\v4\src\java\android\support\v4\view\ViewPager.jav‌​a
```

.

You might debug `ViewPager` to know that is happening exactly, but I wouldn't suggest so until You faced some serious issue with ViewPager. What's why: if you dig into ViewPager code it might lead You to write some hackish code (even not intentionally) on it based on its internal structure and not on its public interface and documentation. So, the main idea of data encapsulation would be ruined which is definitely not good (sadly, sometimes we need to do so in Android due to lack of documentation / unclear naming / android internal issues etc., check [Code Complete by Steve McConnell](http://books.google.co.kr/books?id=3JfE7TGUwvgC&pg=PT141&lpg=PT141&dq=code%20complete%20encapsulation&source=bl&ots=RQu-1M3PeI&sig=MLBRNrKQ9LQSeLjlMK0fXNs_c1Y&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jiJdUNavPKWPiAethoH4Aw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=code%20complete%20encapsulation&f=false) for more details on good encapsulation etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Here the key is that position is different then index. If they give you a position there is no guarantee that your collections haven't removed other positions.

Example:
Let's say your at position 2. destroyItem might have been called for position 0 which means in your collections now position 2 is actually at index 1. So your indexes will quickly become out of sync from your positions. The same thing happens with listview children. I would recommend using a sparseArray instead.

```
private final SparseArray<View> views = new SparseArray<>();

public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    ...
    views.put(position, view);
    ...
}

public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
     View view = views.get(position);
     if (view != null) {
         container.removeView(view);
         views.remove(position);
     }
}
```